# Callback is being called only after big for loop ends

Tags: javascript, web, browser, mqtt, paho

I'm receiving data in browser through websockets (paho-mqtt) but problem is that the receiving callback gets fired only when another task ends (big for loop) and it gets fired with all the stacked data, I'm not losing data just getting delayed. Shouldn't the callback get fired even if there is a loop running? What is happening here?. Otherwise, how can I achieve this, keep receiving while inside a loop?

What I'm trying to say is equivalent to the following:

If I do this in chrome

```
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('hello!');
}, 10);
for (var i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
  console.log('for array');
}
```

I get

```
50000 VM15292:5 for array
VM15292:2 hello!
```

Shouldn't I get something like this?

```
1000 VM15292:5 for array
VM15292:2 hello!
49000 VM15292:5 for array
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The others have diagnosed the problem well, the single threaded nature of the browser.  I will offer a possible solution: generators.

Here's a codepen which demonstrates the problem:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zZwXem?editors=1111

```
window.CP.PenTimer.MAX_TIME_IN_LOOP_WO_EXIT = 60000;

function log(message) {
  const output = document.getElementById('output');
  output.value = output.value + '\n' + message;
}

function asyncTask() {
  log('Simulated websocket message')
}


function doWork() {
  const timer = setInterval(1000, asyncTask);
  let total = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i < 100000000; i++) {
    const foo = Math.log(i) * Math.sin(i);
    total += foo;
  }
  log('The total is: '+ total);
  clearInterval(timer);
}
```

When doWork() is called by clicking the 'Do Work' button, the asyncTask never runs, and the UI locks up.  Horrible UX.

The following example uses a generator to run the long running task.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBmoPZ?editors=1111

```
//Basically disable codepen infinite loop detection, which is faulty for generators
window.CP.PenTimer.MAX_TIME_IN_LOOP_WO_EXIT = 120000;

let workTimer;

function log(message) {
  const output = document.getElementById('output');
  output.value = output.value + '\n' + message;
}

function asyncTask() {
  log('Simulated websocket message')
}

let workGenerator = null;
function runWork() {
  if (workGenerator === null) {
    workGenerator = doWork();
  }
  const work = workGenerator.next();
  if (work.done) {
      log('The total is: '+ work.value);
      workerGenerator = null;
  } else {
    workTimer = setTimeout(runWork,0);
  }
}

function* doWork() {
  const timer = setInterval(asyncTask,1000);
  let total = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i < 100000000; i++) {
    if (i % 100000 === 0) {
      yield;
    }
    if (i % 1000000 == 0) {
      log((i / 100000000 * 100).toFixed(1) + '% complete');
    }
    const foo = Math.log(i) * Math.sin(i);
    total += foo;
  }
  clearInterval(timer);
  return total;
}
```

Here we do work in a generator, and create a generator runner to call from the 'Do Work' button in the UI.  This runs on the latest version of Chrome, I can't speak for other browsers.  Typically you'd use something like babel to compile the generators down to ES5 syntax for a production build.

The generator yields every 10000 rows of calculation, and emits a status update every 100000 rows.  The generator runner 'runWork' creates an instance of the generator and repeatedly calls next().  The generator then runs until it hits the next 'yield' or return statement.  After the generator yields, the generator runner then gives up the UI thread by calling setTimeout with 0 milliseconds and using itself as the handler function.  This typically means it will get called once every animation frame (ideally).  This goes until the generator returns the done flag, at which point the generator runner can get the returned value and clean up.

Here the HTML for the example in case you need to recreate the codepen:

```
<input type='button' value='Do Work' onclick=doWork() />
<textarea id='output' style='width:200px;height:200px'></textarea>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you run JavaScript code in the browser (unless using [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) or other special technologies), it is executed on a single thread. That might not sound too important, but it is.

Your code consists of a for-loop (synchronous) and a call to `setTimeout` (asychronous). Since only one piece of JavaScript can be running at once, your for-loop will never be interrupted by `setTimeout`.

In fact, if your for-loop contained extremely intensive operations that required more than 10 ms to complete, your `setTimeout` callback might actually be *delayed* past that mark, because the browser always wait for the currently executing code to finish before continuing to run the event loop.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('hello!');
}, 10);
for (var i = 0; i < /* 50000 */ 5; i++) {
  console.log('for array');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript engines tends to be single threaded.

So if you are in a long running tight loop that doesn't yield (e.g. to do some io) then the callback will never get a chance to run until the loop finishes